# Where to specify STLSoft path when building pantheios

Tags: c++, pantheios

I am trying to build pantheios using nmake however I get the following message

> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> makefile(18) : fatal error U1050: STLSOFT must be defined Stop.

I downloaded STLSOFT and I looked inside makefile and found the following code

```
CC_INCLUDES_BASE=\
$(INCLUDES_LEADER)\
$(PROJ_INCLUDE)\
-I"$(STLSOFT)\include"\
$(COMMON_INCLUDES)\
$(ENV_INCLUDES)\
 \
```

I wanted to know where I should insert the path for STLSOFT

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System

2) Select "Advance System Settings"

3) Go to "Advanced" tab and then "Environment Variables"

4) Add a New "System Variables". Add "STLSOFT" and the path there with no "\" ending and also exclude "include" at the end of the path.